# MaybeEncodingError при распаралеливании с помощью joblib

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Здравствуйте! Возникает ошибка MaybeEncodingError при распараллеливании.

Делаю следующее:

`trained_models = []
for i in range(len(l) - 1):
    tasks = [joblib.delayed(model)() for model in models[l[i]:l[i+1]]]
    trained_models.append(joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=n_cpu)(tasks))`

Вот так выглядит model: `functools.partial(<function train_model at 0x7f89337e7d90>, functools.partial(<class 'models.monolayer_rnn.MonolayerRNN'>, n_features=19, n_instruments=13, n_gru0=30))`

Она возвращает объект `models.monolayer_rnn.MonolayerRNN object at 0x7f893382d0b8`.

Полный код ошибки:

```
MaybeEncodingError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c74bd2fce434> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', "l = list(range(0, len(models), n_cpu))\nl.append(len(models))\ntrained_models = []\nfor i in range(len(l) - 1):\n    tasks = [joblib.delayed(model)() for model in models[l[i]:l[i+1]]]\n    trained_models.append(joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=n_cpu)(tasks))\n    print(l[i+1], 'done of ', l[-1])")

/root/miniconda/envs/jupyterhub_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2291             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2292             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2293                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2294             return result
   2295 

/root/miniconda/envs/jupyterhub_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/root/miniconda/envs/jupyterhub_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/root/miniconda/envs/jupyterhub_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1165         else:
   1166             st = clock2()
-> 1167             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1168             end = clock2()
   1169             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

/root/miniconda/envs/jupyterhub_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    664                 # consumption.
    665                 self._iterating = False
--> 666             self.retrieve()
    667             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    668             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

/root/miniconda/envs/jupyterhub_py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    516                 self._lock.release()
    517             try:
--> 518                 self._output.append(job.get())
    519             except tuple(self.exceptions) as exception:
    520                 try:

/root/miniconda/envs/jupyterhub_py3/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    597             return self._value
    598         else:
--> 599             raise self._value
    600 
    601     def _set(self, i, obj):

MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<models.monolayer_rnn.MonolayerRNN object at 0x7f893382d0b8>'. Reason: 'RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object',)'
```

Как можно решить проблему, не меняя возвращаемое значение model?

Comment: Настоящая ошибка - `maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object`. И чем не устраивает стандартный `multiprocessing`, что пришлось тащить какую-то непонятную жажу?

Comment: Гуглил ошибку в интернете, со стандартным `multiprocessing` возникает такая же ошибка.

Comment: @ТолкачёвИван: для передачи объектов между процессами, они сериализируются в байты, используя `pickle` (в `multiprocessing` и по-видимому `joblib`). `pickle` НЕ зависит от `multiprocessing` или `joblib`. Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку, выполните `pickle.dumps()` на указанном объекте типа `models.monolayer_rnn.MonolayerRNN` (узнайте, является ли *"RuntimeError(maximum recursion depth exceeded)"* багом в методе `__getstate__()` объекта или просто объект глубоковложенный--увеличьте `sys.setrecursionlimit()` в последнем случае)